# convert `boost::tuple` to `boost::fusion::tuple`

Tags: c++, boost, tuples, boost-fusion

I need to convert a `boost::tuple` to the corresponding `boost::fusion::tuple`. I have figured out the corresponding type.

But I expect there is an inbuilt function to do this. I really don't want to reinvent such things. I have searched in the boost fusion documentation but didn't find any.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[c++14](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b14) version:

```
template<std::size_t...Is, class T>
auto to_fusion( std::index_sequence<Is...>, T&& in ) {
  using std::get;
  return boost::fusion::make_tuple( get<Is>(std::forward<T>(in))... );
}
template<class...Ts>
auto to_fusion( boost::tuple<Ts...> in ) {
  return to_fusion( std::make_index_sequence<::boost::tuples::length< boost::tuple<Ts...>>::value>{}, std::move(in) );
}
template<class...Ts>
boost::fusion::tuple<Ts...> to_fusion( std::tuple<Ts...> in ) {
  return to_fusion( std::make_index_sequence<sizeof...(Ts)>{}, std::move(in) );
}
```

I am unaware of a built-in version.

Add trailing `-> decltype(boost::fusion::make_tuple( get<Is>(std::forward<T>(in))... ))` in [c++11](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b11).  You also need `make_index_sequence`, which probably has a boost equivalent.

[Live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/51e8eafcd00880ff).

Comment: should the `Ts...` be `Is...` ? Also I am getting `type/value` mismatch even after I change `Ts ` to `Is`

Comment: @NeelBasu Sorry, typo.

Comment: @NeelBasu I'm relying on ADL to find the right `get`.  I'm just bringing in a "known" template get, so prior to ADL the compiler sees it as a template.

Comment: I am getting `/usr/include/boost/tuple/detail/tuple_basic.hpp:133:33: error: no type named ‘head_type’ in ‘boost::tuples::detail::drop_front<2>::apply<boost::tuples::cons<point_2d<double>, boost::tuples::cons<point_2d<double>, boost::tuples::null_type> > >::type’ {aka ‘struct boost::tuples::null_type’}`

Comment: `make_index_sequence<sizeof...(Ts)>` -> `index_sequence_for<Ts...>`?

Comment: @Caleth Sure, but `index_sequence_for` always seemed like waste.  I don't really think it should exist.

Comment: @NeelBasu I added a [live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9f2d6c85eecbb873) of the code running.  Ah, nm, problem is with `boost::tuple` not `std::get`.  One second.

Comment: @NeelBasu Fixed.  The problem is that `boost::tuple` is written in a pre-C++11 way with "null" elements instead of variardic.  So I cannot use its template argument count to work out how long it is.

Answer (score 3):

You might use something like:

```
template <class Tuple>
auto to_fusion(Tuple&& tuple)
{
    std::apply(
        [](auto&&... args){
            return boost::fusion::make_tuple(decltype(args)(args)...);
        },
        std::forward<Tuple>(tuple));
}
```

Comment: Ooo, [tag:C++17].